# Sorting array by float value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I am having some trouble sorting an array by a float value. I have searched around the web, and I understand that I have to use a comparision function, but I am having issues understanding the concept.

I am using this code to read an xlxs file and pushing the values I need to a simpler array. I need to sort this array by the value of the top2box key so the highest value is key 0.

Here is my current code

```
// data is an array of arrays, lets loop through it to sort. The array contains each row of my xlxs file.

    var hon = [] //array that will hold the sorted entries from the excel file        

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        // we dont want empty data. each row has a key named Business Unit. In empty rows the value of the key is the name of the key. We dont need that data.
        if (data[i][3] != '' && data[i][0] != 'Business Unit') {

            // data belongs to an actual person
            // round top2box to display the percentage.

            // push the values we need to a simpler array
            hon.push({
                country: data[i][0],
                team: data[i][2],
                name: data[i][3],
                top2box: data[i][4],
                sumofvotes: data[i][5]
            })
        }
    }

    // loop done lets sort each array entry by top2box value. So highest top2box is the first entry of the array
    hon.sort(function(a,b) { return a.top2box - b.top2box;});

    // show the result.
    console.log(JSON.stringify(hon, null, 4));
```

However when displaying the results all of the top2box entries have been changed to "1" and is not sorted (probable due to this aswell)

The values of hon is a float, which will need to be shown as a percentage later on. Here are some example values. I need to maintain these exact values, but order them highest to lowest, so I can loop through the array and display them as html later.

```
"country": "Norway",
"team": "NO-Aftersales",
"name": "Andersen, Dennis",
"top2box": "0.47368421052631599",
"sumofvotes": "19"
```

Here is another

```
"country": "Sweden",
"team": "SE-AS",
"name": "Vuong, Adele",
"top2box": "0.51515151515151503",
"sumofvotes": "33"
```

SOLUTION

Turns out JSON.stringify(); was the root of the problem. Removing this from the console.log. So it instead is console.log(hon) shows the correct data and also sorts them correctly. Json stringify is not treating floats very nice.

Comment: *So highest top2box is the first entry* then it should be `b - a`. Also please explain *top2box entries have been changed to "1"*

Comment: Have you initialized hon?

Comment: oh sorry. Hon is initialized and displays correctly yes. @Rajesh Take a look at this screenshot of the output http://imgur.com/a/s3Qvy Top2Box i supposed to display percentage values. Second screenshot shows the correct values that I want to maintain, but sorted.

Comment: From your screenshot it seems like `top2box` is a string, you have to parse it before doing comparison inside `sort`. Try `parseFloat(a.top2box) - parseFloat(b.top2box)` and also you have update `hon` with sorted value, `hon = hon.sort()`.

Comment: @azs06 thanks for replying. I tried it out and altered the sort function like so: `hon = hon.sort((a, b) => {return parseFloat(a.top2box) - parseFloat(b.top2box)}); // save the sort result` but the result is the same. All top2box values is now 1.

Comment: Could you update the question with some value of `hon?`

Comment: @n0rd Issue is not caused by any code that you have shared. Please look at you complete code as to where value is updated

Comment: @Rajesh I am not manipulating the output anywhere else. If I comment out the sort function I have added and simply display the content of the array as is. It displays correctly. As soon as i uncomment the sorting function all values are changed to 1 again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the result of 'sort' like this:

```
var hon = [
{
    country: 'some country',
    team: 'some team',
    name: 'some name',
    top2box: 123123,
    sumofvotes: 123123
},
{
    country: 'some country2',
    team: 'some team2',
    name: 'some name2',
    top2box: 123,
    sumofvotes: 123
}
];

hon = hon.sort((a, b) => {return a.top2box - b.top2box}); // save the sort result
// (a - b) = Ascending sort, (b - a) = Descending sort

console.log(hon);
```

You can read more about sort here - [Array#Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and about Arrow functions here - [Functions#ArrowFunctions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried this, but it changes all the values of top2box to 1.

`{
        "country": "Denmark",
        "team": "DK-Aftersales",
        "name": "Skaaning, Rasmus",
        "top2box": "1",
        "sumofvotes": "4"
    },

    {
        "country": "Sweden",
        "team": "",
        "name": "Rosenius, Niklas",
        "top2box": "1",
        "sumofvotes": "1"
    }`

originally they are float values. Example: 0.241232 I need to maintain this, but sort them by highest to lowest.

Comment: 'Sort' can't change the type or value of prop.
To sort them by highest to lowest you need to use 'b - a'.

Comment: `(a, b) => {return a.top2box - b.top2box}` is an overkill (*at least to me*). You can directly do `(a, b) => a.top2box - b.top2box`

Comment: @Rajesh I am now sorting like so: `hon = hon.sort((a, b) => a.top2box - b.top2box);` All top2box values in the output is now "1" instead of the original float values.

Comment: @n0rd, I think that you doing transform of hon, or top2box somewhere in your module.

Comment: @fauster01 Hm. But that does not explain why it only occurs when I try and sort it. When I am not sorting the values do not change. It seems like the value is being rounded since the original values have the format: 0.1232321 for example. But if I simply multiply the values with 100 to get positive value, all numbers = 100 after sorting. Without sorting it shows correctly (12.32321)

Comment: @fauster01 Progress! Turns out removing JSON.stringify() and simply console.log(hon) instead sorts and shows the correct numbers. The issue has to be a problem with json.stringify.